# A model of fox and rabbit population with baseline conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-modeling

> The population of foxes and rabbits on Nantucket Island has been studied by biologists. They measure the populations relative to a baseline, in hundreds of animals. (So  $x(2)=5$  means that there are  500  more foxes than the baseline value, and  $y(2)=−5$  means that there are  500  fewer rabbits than the baseline value.)
>
> The biologists have established the following relationship between $x(t)$ (foxes' population) and $y(t)$ (rabbits' population):
>   \begin{align}
> x' &= 0.5x + y \\
> y' &= -2.25x + 0.5y
> \end{align}
>
> Suppose that at $t=0$ there are $100$ more foxes than the baseline: $x(0) = 1$; the rabbit population is at the baseline value, $y(0) = 0$. What is the solution to this initial value problem?

From solving the characteristic equations, I got that $\lambda = 0.5 \pm 1.5i$. Since using either value yields the same answer, let $\lambda = 0.5 - 1.5i$. Then from solving the system for the eigenvector, I get that the eigenvector is $\binom{i}{1.5}$. Hence the complex solution is $\binom{i}{1.5}e^{(0.5 - 1.5i)t}$.

Using the Euler's formula $e^{iwt} = \cos(\omega t) + i\sin(\omega t)$, I get the real parts of $x$ and $y$ is given by

$$\binom{x}{y} = e^{0.5t} \binom{0}{1.5} \cos(1.5t) + e^{0.5t}\binom{1}{0} \sin(1.5t).$$

And given that $x(0) = 1$ and $y(0) = 0$, I arrived at:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \sin(1.5t) e^{0.5t} + e^{0.5t} \\
y(t) &= 1.5\cos(1.5t) e^{0.5t} - 1.5e^{0.5t}
\end{align}

However, these equations turned out to be the wrong model.

Comment: (1) The command `\choose` is a plain TeX command, and does not play nice with LaTeX nor MathJax.  Use `\binom{a}{b}` instead.  (2) Why is this the "wrong" model?  Is this an exercise from a text?  If so, which text?

Comment: It's not an exercise from a text, but homework from a class (I don't think we have a text). I was marked wrong for my answers.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm wondering if this is because they're looking for a general solution involving both eigenvalues/eigenvectors

Comment: You should always check your work. For your proffered solution, $$x'(t) = 1.5e^{t/2}\cos(1.5t) + 0.5e^{t/2}\sin(1.5t) + 0.5e^{t/2}$$ while $$0.5x + y = 1.5e^{t/2}\cos(1.5t) + 0.5e^{t/2}\sin(1.5t) - e^{t/2}$$